# How can I split camelCase with Regex without splitting McDonald?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation

Using the following pattern I can split camelCase: `(\w*?[a-z]{1})([A-Z]{1})`

But how can I avoid matching common names like McDonald or DeSanto?

I'm after:

```
Match: camelCase
Match: NewsToday
No Match: IBM
No Match: McDonalds (matches pattern above)
No Match: DeSanto   (matches pattern above)
```

Comment: Maybe `\b(?!Mc|De)(\w*?[a-z])([A-Z])`? ``\b(?!(?:Mc|De)[A-Z])(\w*?[a-z])([A-Z])``? See https://regex101.com/r/TAm0as/1. Note that `.*?` does not match any text if it is at the end of a regex pattern. `{1}` are always redundant, it is the default behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```php
\b(?!Mc|De)(\w*?[a-z])([A-Z])
\b(?!(?:Mc|De)[A-Z])(\w*?[a-z])([A-Z])
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/TAm0as/1) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/TAm0as/2).

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?!Mc|De)` - a  negative lookahead that fails the match if there is `Mc` or `De` immediately to the right of the current location
- `(\w*?[a-z])` - Group 1: zero or more word chars as few as possible and then a lowercase letter
- `([A-Z])` - Group 2: an uppercase letter.